# Invalid Conversion from a DLL Call

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am referencing my project to an external DLL which I got from a hardware vendor and encountered this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Additional information: Conversion from string "8010001D" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

However there is no compilation error in Visual Studio 2017, only runtime crash. A colleague could debug it fine in Visual Studio 2012. I have tried to change the targeted platfrom from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5 but still failed.

Here is the source code. At the moment I am just trying to see if the referencing is fine or not but it shouldn't have any problem IMO.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyKad reader = new MyKad(); //the app breaks here. MyKad() is a dll object
        Console.WriteLine("Testing app starts..");
        if(reader.Connect())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Obj creation succeed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Obj creation failed");
        }
    }
}
```

`MyKad()` is from dll. I can see the methods info but not the actual code. Did I miss any legacy settings in the project configurations?

Below is the callstack

```
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger( Value) Line 788 + 0x84 bytes    Basic
CSMyKad.dll!CSMyKad.MyKad.UserControl_Initialize() + 0x73 bytes 
CSMyKad.dll!CSMyKad.MyKad.MyKad() + 0x11e bytes 
MyKadLib.exe!MyKadLib.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 16   C#
```

Comment: The error is quite clear... It is trying to convert `8010001D` to an integer... Perhaps something in the app.config, or it is a default value

Comment: Yes it is quite clear but it is from the DLL. I wonder how can this DLL ran fine in VS2012. I ll try to take a look at the app.config

Comment: No such hex value appears in config. It is a constant embedded in DLL I think which were meant to use as byte.

Comment: If you can't find anything, the other trick is to take a look at the dll (MyKad) with [IlSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases). Your call stack is probably longer than you wrote us... You look at the method referenced there and try to divine where it takes the number from and how it tries to convert it. The number could be from the registry or from who-knows-where

Comment: You have a precise address here... Launch Ilspy and take a look at the UserControl_Initialize.

Comment: I know that i can dissect the DLL but can I change it? Kinda pointless if I cant. I just wonder how can this DLL works in 2012 tho. thanks

Comment: Fairly typical outcome of the stringly type programming style that vb.net makes possible.  Using Option Strict On is a good way to flush out these kind of bugs, assuming you have source.  It fails on error handling code, the kind that never gets tested.  "8010001D" is an error code in hexadecimal, means SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE, "The Smart card resource manager is not running."

Comment: @HansPassant Actually that solved that problem. Please put it as answer! I knew it has to do with the debugging settings.